# How do I implement a menu like MS Security Essentials settings tab

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

[image: MS Security Essentials]

It looks like a ListView on the left and with every click event on a ListViewItem the corresponding panel gets enabled/visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just as you said: a simple listview on the left, and panels on the right.
On the `SelectionChanged` event of the listview, hide/show the desired panels (change the visibility of the panels).

Answer (score 1):

Its just a list box control on the left and when you click on the listitem the relative panel is made visible and previous viewed panel is made visible =false

so for this you have to use

ListBox Control
Panel Controol